# How to cross-reference theorems with "Theorem"?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I use

```
\begin{lemma} \label{aaa} ... \end{lemma}
\begin{theorem} \label{bbb} ... \end{theorem}
```

and many other similar kinds in the same document.

When I cross-reference those lemmas and theorems somewhere in the manuscript, I don't remember if I named it a lemma or a theorem, but I perhaps remember the label name. When I just `\ref{aaa}`, it only gives the number; so I have to put something like `Lemma \ref{aaa}` or `Theorem \ref{bbb}`. How can I print "Lemma 1" when it is a lemma, and "Theorem 2", when it is a theorem, without explicitly typing "Lemma" and "Theorem"?

Comment: I find RefTeX mightily useful, with some combination of keys it will bring a list of choices to choose from, and it will produce the `\ref{aaa}` automatically.  Too bad not many other software provides this function.

Comment: I would advise you to name your labels using prefixes like `\label{lem:lemma}` or `\label{theo:theorem}` or similar.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)'s `\autoref` function does this for you. It's neat. I believe there's also [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem)'s `\thref` and the [`theoremref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/theoremref) package. And finally, there is the [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package.

To get custom names with hyperref you need to add `\newcommand{\xxxautorefname}{Xxx}`, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}
\newcommand{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}
\newcommand{\remarkautorefname}{Remark}
\newcommand{\propositionautorefname}{Proposition}
\newcommand{\exampleautorefname}{Example}
```

Comment: `\autoref` doesn't work out of the box on custom defined theorems. `theoremref` doesn't seem to work on figures.