# Referencing theorems, lemmas, etc by name

Tags: cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to cross-reference theorems with “Theorem”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33226/how-to-cross-reference-theorems-with-theorem)

I have had this doubt for quite a long time but I am unable to work out a way. This problem concerns referring back to definitions, equations, theorems, lemmas in a mathematical write-up of any sort:

Please consider the following code:

```
 \documentclass{amsart}
 \usepackage{amsthm}

 \newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
 \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
 \begin{document}
 This is an example. 

 \begin{defn} \label{ring}
 A commutative ring $R$ with unity is an abelian group with a binary operation  $\cdot $
(frequently referred to as multiplication) which is associative, commutative and has an identity. 
 \end{defn}


\begin{thm} \label{0pro}
$0_R \cdot r = 0_R$ for all $r \in R$
\end{thm}

The proof of Theorem \ref{0pro} follows from definition \ref{ring}. 

 \end{document}
```

In referring back to a theorem, one has to say `Theorem \ref{0pro}`. My doubt is that it must be possible to automise this: as in every instance of a reference to a theorem must come automatically as `Theorem <blah>` instead of having to manually type this in.

Example: `\ref{0pro}` must print `Theorem 1` and similar goes for others.

Is there a hack or a work around?

Comment: Use `\nameref` of `hyperref` or `\cref` of `cleveref` package for this purpose.

Comment: D'oh! Didn't search through the site properly. Voting to close.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{cleveref}` to your preamble *after* loading `amsthm`, but *before* issuing `\newtheorem`. In the text body, use `\cref` instead of `\ref`.

Comment: @lockstep Thank you. But, is this not compatible with hyperref just in case someone wanted to use those hyperlinks in the .pdf document?

Comment: `cleveref` is one of the packages that must be loaded *after* `hyperref`.

Comment: @lockstep Thanks, now the errors are gone! :)