# How to get \ref to automatically output Table, Appendix etc.?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir

When I use `\ref` my output is just the number of the table or letter of the appendix. So for example in my MWE below when I enter See `\ref{Test1}` my output is See 1.1 and for See `\ref{AppendixA}` output is See A.

Is there a way to have the output to be See Table 1.1 and See Appendix A?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a test chapter}
hello there, please see \ref{AppendixA}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Test & Table \\
1    & 2     \\
3    &      
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test Table}
\label{Test1}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1] Please see \ref{Test1}

\appendix
\chapter{This is a test Appendix} % Main appendix title
\label{AppendixA} % For referencing this appendix elsewhere, use \ref{AppendixA}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to get more complete references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5767/5764); [How to cross-reference theorems with “Theorem”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33226/5764); [Using section sign (§) for cross-references to sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59889/5764). Biggest suggestion here is to add [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and use `\autoref` instead of just `\ref`.

Comment: @Werner Indeed duplicates, can't believe I missed them after about an hour of looking through questions!. Thanks for the `\autoref`tip. Using `hyperref`package already so that is handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several packages which can achieve this, `cleveref` seems to be the most advanced and most customizable one.

At least if the chapter in their documentation fits:

> Given how useful automated cross-reference typesetting is,
>   there are naturally  a number of other LaTeX packages with similar goals to cleveref,
>   most notably varioref, fancyref, hyperref’s \autoref command, and 
>   (for theorem-like environments) ntheorem with the thref option. 
>   (There are many others, but these come closest to providing similar features to cleveref.)
>   However, all have certain deficiencies which cleveref attempts to overcome.

If you want to use cleveref for the start just replace your `\ref` commands with `\cref`.

**Important** note: cleveref should be the last package you load, even after hyperref

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

%% All you packages here

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a test chapter}
hello there, please see \cref{AppendixA}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Test & Table \\
1    & 2     \\
3    &      
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test Table}
\label{Test1}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1] Please see \cref{Test1}

\appendix
\chapter{This is a test Appendix} % Main appendix title
\label{AppendixA} % For referencing this appendix elsewhere, use \ref{AppendixA}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```